# Creating / Managing users remotely

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I've put my site online and I'm looking to add/change user membership. From Visual Studio, I can access the Website Administration Tool WSAT and it's great if you just want to add users manually. Is there a similar way to change users once the site is hosted on a remote server?

For the moment, I change the user information through the WSAT and re-FTP the mdf file; it's pretty painful. Let me know if there's a better way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there are only two options.

1. If you have control of the server
   you can enable access to the WSAT on
   the server.
2. Code up your own little management system.

[Here's a link](http://nishantpant.wordpress.com/2008/05/22/how-to-provide-aspnetwebadminfiles-wsat-like-user-management-for-your-hosted-or-online-site/) that covers both in a little more depth.  That link also references the [4guysfromrolla.com tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020202857/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120705-1.aspx) which, while dated, is still relevant.

Comment: There's also a 3rd option, you can execute the aspnet stored proc's directly in the database, but they're not very well documented. The best option IMO is to add your own Admin section to your website.